# Permalinks not working on second wordpress installed in a subdirect

Tags: htaccess, directory

I have a main wordpress installed on the root and now due to a long story about incompatible plugins I need to install a second full instance of wordpress in a subdirectory.

The main site works fine, as does the site in the subdirectory. As long as I don't activate pretty permalinks on the subsite

Once the subsite has permalinks on only the home page is accessible, any other page is captured by the main install that spits out a 404.

I have the following on my main .htaccess (in the root folder of the site)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

<Directory /path/to/subdir>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdir/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /subdir/index.php [L]
</Directory>
```

And this is the content of the .htaccess that resides in the subfolder

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdir/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /subdir/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I thought that either the .htaccess in the subdirectory or the `<Directory>` directive in the main .htaccess would work. I'm clueless at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time this problem gets solved after flushing the permalinks. By that I mean, one just needs to hit 'Save changes' on 'Permalink settings' page on backend. However you said that you tried pretty permalinks and its not working.

Under "Settings > General", please confirm that you have updated "WordPress Address (URL)" and "Site Address (URL)" to subdirectory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!Under "Setting > General" the site url contains the subdirectory. I have also tried to switch back and forth between different permalink settings but the only one that works is the "Default" option with the query string in the URL.

Comment: Please make sure that the .htaccess in sub-directory is writable by WordPress

Comment: I have just checked and it is writable, but wordpress does not change the settings there when I switch from default to pretty permalinks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please create a subdomain? Your sub directory will be point via subdomain with fresh htaccess file.
And i hope the following code is not in your sub directory.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com

RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```