# .htaccess for wordpress inside another wordpress install

Tags: htaccess, directory

I have a main WordPress installation, with this (normal) `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And I have a different WP installation under `/conekt`, with this `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /conekt/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  . /conekt/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Each have their own db, and each point to the `root`and `root/conekt` folders respectively.
(Edit: I actually found this to be incorrect: <strike>The main WP works fine</strike>).

The subfolder WP front page and admin both work fine, but none of the front-end links (of the subfolder WP) work, with a custom permalink set to `[root/conekt/]%postname%`.

I've tried resetting permalinks for the subfolder WP, but still no go. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to catch all calls for `/conekt/` in the `.htaccess` from root? If so, how? I'm not an expert in `.htaccess` rules.

I've already browsed through these questions, but haven't been able to find an answer for my problem in any of them:

- [Wordpress within a subdirectory of another Wordpress environment doesn't work](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/228394/wordpress-within-a-subdirectory-of-another-wordpress-environment-doesnt-work?rq=1)
- [Permalinks not working on second wordpress installed in a subdirect](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165780/permalinks-not-working-on-second-wordpress-installed-in-a-subdirect?rq=1)

**Update:** Everything works perfectly when I select default permalinks for the WP inside the folder. Links only stop working when I try to use pretty permalinks (which is what is desired).

Comment: Have you considered using a multi-site approach? Or viewing the [Installing Multiple Blogs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_Multiple_Blogs) form the codex?

Comment: @GregMcMullen I haven't. If this doesn't work, I'll try it, thank you. However, I don't see any point in a multisite installation, since I don't want to use the same database and no data is shared between the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a server missconfiguration in `httpd.conf`:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

had to be changed in `AllowOverride All`. I should have realized this sooner, but it eluded me since I thought the override was working on the main installation, but it wasn't. I didn't notice it, because it was a one-page website. Once I turned `AllowOverride` on, they both started working.

First impulse was to delete the question, but than I thought it might help other people pulling their hair out, like I was.

Again, thank you for your time to everyone who read this.

Comment: This was driving me nuts!  Especially since similar setups on other servers were working perfectly!  Thanks for posting the solution!